# Does MarkLogic LDAP external authentication work with LDAPS?

Tags: authentication, ldap, marklogic, marklogic-8

We have LDAP working with MarkLogic. We are successfully using LDAP for external authentication and authorization. However, MarkLogic keeps throwing us a warning in the logs about not using LDAPS. We have tried LDAPS with both 'simple' and 'MD5' as bind methods but it does not work with our LDAPS url LDAP service (It works with just LDAP). We need to use LDAPS for security reasons but have been unsuccessful so far. What am I missing in the settings? Does MarkLogic work with LDAPS? (It does not show LDAPS in the documentation.)

```
Warning: External Security OUR-external-ldap should use ldaps (ldap with SSL) because the bind method is simple.
```

Comment: Please define in more detail what "it doe not work" means when you have tried simple and md5.  The issue may be that you are using certs on your LDAP server that need to be registered in MarkLogic.  Expanding your answer with error messages about the things you tried and fialed may help people understand better.

Comment: I cannot log in to the MarkLogic qconsole when I point external authentication to our LDAPS url. (i.e. It does not work.)

Comment: Can you provide more detail on the settings used in the `OUR-external-ldap`? Make sure the url starts with `ldaps:`, and as mentioned by David, you need to register the cert of your LDAP server inside ML using for instance http://docs.marklogic.com/pki:insert-trusted-certificates

Comment: Also, consider trying out the external auth on a separate rest-api app server before applying it to the built-in ports of MarkLogic..

Comment: I did use the **ldaps:** prefix. However, I need to look at the trusted certs. That may be it. Thanks for that insight!